# bootstrap 3 navbar padding and items background

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 to build a website. Could anyone please tell me how to remove the padding / margin for the menu items? It currently looks like this:

[image: Bootstrap 3 navbar]

And I would also like to have different link colors when hovering the items. My code is currently like this:

```
  <!-- Start main navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Politica</a></li>
        <li class="headerDivider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Societate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Economie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Extern</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stil de viata</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:#303334;
    color:#ffffff;
border-radius:0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
color:#fff;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-nav >      .active > a:focus {
color: #ffffff;
background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #007faa;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
color:#eeeeee;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
background-color:#eeeeee;
}

.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
background-color:#007faa;
}

.navbar-nav {
font: 400 1.3em 'Oswald', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;    
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fa-home {
font-size: 1.2em;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net? Or some CSS? You arent using Bootstrap defaults so its a little tricky to diagnose..

Comment: added the css as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3908/)** you can remove the padding using:

```
.navbar {
    border: none; /* optional depending on your requirements */
}

.nav > li > a {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

To add different hover state colors, you can use e.g.:

```
.nav > li > a:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the paddig answer, it works! As for the hover, could you please continue the fiddle with the example you posted? I'm guessing there should be different class names for each buttons, correct? PS: I'm taking about the hover background, not text-color. That should remain white.

Comment: @Andrei P you should accept this answer since it answers your original question about the padding.

Comment: HTML is so damn fickle. Trial and error the hell out of everything and it never works as expected.

Comment: @SW4 What happens when you change the style of your inner link from `padding-left` and `padding-right` to `padding: 0 20px`

Answer (score 1):

Just write this code in css

.nav > li > a {

```
padding: 0 !important;
```

}
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
     color:#fff;
     padding:0px !important;
}
```

Thanks